# Spotfire Redirecting to home after link click

Tags: redirect, spotfire

Ask: Have a button that when clicked downloads a file from a folder on the server and remains on the current page.

Current state and problem: I have a CustomWizardPromptControlPage that writes a simple button to the HTMLTextWriter. The onclick event for the button fires off a window.open(urlToDocument, '_blank'). By doing the button with the onclick it does actually allow me to download the file, however the parent page redirects to the home page.

Already tried: href - didn't download the file and redirected me to the home page. form submit - didn't do anything.

If anyone can give me some insight as to why Spotfire does this and what I can do to stop it from happening it would be greatly appreciated

--Follow up with working code sample for comments request

```
namespace ACompanyName.SpotFire.ExportWithFilters
{
    public class ExportWithFiltersWebPromptControl : CustomWizardPromptControl
    {
        public ExportWithFiltersWebPromptControl(ExportWithFiltersFileSettings settings)
        {
            this.AddPage(new ExportWithFiltersPage(settings));
        }

        private class ExportWithFiltersPage : CustomWizardPromptControlPage
        {
            private readonly ExportWithFiltersFileSettings _settings;

            public ExportWithFiltersPage(ExportWithFiltersFileSettings settings) : base("Export with Filters")
            {
                _settings = settings;
            }

            protected override void OnGetContentsCore(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            {
                var domain = "https://dev.AURL.com";
                var filename = _settings.ExportWithFiltersFileInfo.Name;
                var fullFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", domain, "Exports", filename);
                writer.WriteLine("<a href='{0}' target=\"_blank\">Download Export with Filters</a>", fullFilePath);
            }

            protected override void OnGetScriptsCore(StringBuilder builder)
            {
            }

            protected override void OnLeavePageCore(FormData data)
            {
            }

            protected override bool OnValidatePromptCore(FormData data)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share some code of what you have so far, please ?

Comment: Apparently Spotfire didn't like the button with an onClick event. Replaced it with just a <a> link with the onClick event instead of a href and it worked for my needs.

Comment: Thx for the comment but I didnt find any place where CustomWizardPromptControlPage is used so it would be kind if you shared your working example.

Comment: Added Jacek Sierajewski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that Spotfire didn't like putting `<button>` into the page. Swapped it out with an hyperlink with a target of blank and it worked like a charm. If a button is still desired, stylized div should do the trick.

Comment: I wrestled with this for a few hours today. wish I had remembered seeing your post here! my solution was to use `<input type="button" />` instead of `<button>`. seems that there's something in the Web Player's JS library that attaches an `onClick` to all `<button>`s and has them navigate away from the current view (in 10.2 it will close the current document). I'll be submitting this as a possible bug.

Comment: ok, word back from support is that actually this is a browser behavior! turns out that, in Chrome, a `<button>`'s `type` attribute defaults to `type="submit"`, which will, you know, submit the form. you can confirm this by putting together a simple form and testing it in a couple of browsers. the issue can be solved with `<button type="button" ... />`. bit redundant but hey.